# What are the pros and cons of transforming data to unit variance (just scaling by std) vs standardizing ? This is prior to use it PCA on stock returns

Tags: pca

I am working with dataset of stock returns and plannig to use PCA. I need to decide on standardizing (centering the returns and then dividing by standard deviation) or simply dividing by std. The question is what are the pros and cons of both methods. Standardizing seems to be the default option, but by centering the data, I am getting rid of the "trend" on returns which I believe contains valuable information.

Comment: If you keep track of how you standardize (that is, the mean and std for each feature), then can't you undo that standardization after the PCA?

Comment: What do you hope to get out of the PCA?

Comment: I would like to create historical series of the first pcs and observe their behaviour

Comment: Thanks for your interest Adrian. I could keep track of mean and std, but since riskier stocks have higher returns they will dominate the less risky ones. That is why I always consider dividing by std. The part I am not clear is about mean centering. Intutitively I am ok with having variables on the same scale (unit variance).